# Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp) takes 15-20 seconds

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop, com-interop

I have question, is it normal that line of code:

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp)
```

takes about 20 seconds? I tried with FinalReleaseComObject() method and time is still too long. Does anybody can tell me how can i fix it?

```
WordApp.Documents documents = null;
WordApp.Document doc = null;
WordApp.Application wordApp = new WordApp.Application();
wordApp.Visible = false;
wordApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
try
{
   documents = wordApp.Documents;
   doc = documents.Open();
   doc.ExportAsFixedFormat();
   doc.Close(ref saveChanges);
}
finally
{
   wordApp.Quit();
   if (doc != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);             // takes few ms
   if (documents != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(documents); // takes few ms
   if (wordApp != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp);     // takes 15-20 seconds
   wordApp = null;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly normal.  But anything is possible, Word is a giant program with a lot of self-healing behavior that you tend to induce by debugging.  And anti-malware rarely leaves it in peace.  Try another machine.

Comment: Do you use a non-cached Exchange mode?

Comment: Thanks Hans, but I cant try on another machine, I have only one server. Eugene, how can I verify what mode I use?

Comment: @Pawel, if you don't precede people's names with @ they won't see your comment. But you do know you shouldn't automate Office applications in a server environment? Correctly, you should explicitly be setting all these objects to `null` before trying to force a release. And it's quite possible that Word is simply taking that long to finish exporting, saving and QUIT.